# MYSQL query code to check if statement and get row values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

so I was trying to use if statement on MySQL. I have a table contains tp1 column and in this column I have two different string values L1_ON or L1_OFF, I want to get L1_ON if there is one on tp1 column but if there is no L1_ON just get L1_OFF. this is what wrote and i know it's not correct just for extra explanation.

```
$query1 = sprintf('SELECT id,dateandtime,tp1 FROM plate WHERE AND  IF(tp1 LIKE "L1_ON") else (tp1 LIKE "L1_OFF") ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1');
```

Comment: Are you saying you want it to either match the string "L1_ON" and return that, or if it doesn't (regardless of the value) then "L1_OFF"?

Comment: yes i want to get L1_ON, but if i couldn't get it just bring me L1_OFF, so basically don't want to get null value

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful. Also, can there be multiple rows with l1_on for a given id?

Comment: yes i take care of multiple rows but i just want to check the whole table for L1_ON, cause my table restart each night all to L1_OFF so, next day i don't want to get null value i want the system to give me L1_OFF

Answer (score 0):

If "L1_ON" and "L1_OFF" are the only possible values, then you could just sort by `tp1` column to ensure "L1_ON" columns come up first:

```sql
SELECT 
  id,dateandtime,tp1
FROM plate
ORDER BY tp1 DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

If there could be more than those two values, and you're using this in a script, honestly I would probably just run two queries. One trying to get "L1_ON" values, then a second getting all other values.

```sql
SELECT 
  id,dateandtime,tp1
FROM plate
WHERE tp1 = "L1_ON"
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Finally, if you really want to do this in one query, you could union two queries, one for all "L1_ON" values, followed by one for any that are NOT "L1_ON"

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM (
  SELECT 
    id,
    dateandtime,
    tp1
  FROM plate
  WHERE tp1 = "L1_ON"
  ORDER BY id ASC
) AS tp1_on

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id,
    dateandtime,
    tp1
  FROM plate
  WHERE tp1 != "L1_ON"
  ORDER BY id ASC
) AS tp1_off

LIMIT 1
```

Comment: almost there but i want to give the priority to L1_ON if there is L1_ON don't need for L1_OFF

Comment: what you just did even if i have L1_ON still give me L1_OFF

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sir, what you just did is similar to the first answer, just give me L1_OFF, but i already told you the priority for L1_ON.  
to put this in best way .....> if L1_ON exists display it to me and ignore L1_OFF>
if L1_ON not excites display to me L1_OFF.

Answer (score 0):

using if statement I found the best answer to my question like following:

```
$query  = sprintf('SELECT IF (tp1 REGEXP "L1_ON" ,dateandtime ,"L1_OFF") id,dateandtime,tp1 FROM plate  ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 ');
```

so the code check if tp1 has L1_ON then give me time for that raw, if not just give any L1_OFF raw with time (dateandtime= time of L1_..  raw).